# Can we extract chemical energy remotely?

Tags: energy, electrochemistry

To state directly. Can we use any electromagnetic method to extract energy from fat?

Humanity store useless fat inside their body. And to work out mechanically leads to frustration of tireness and ,sometimes ,injury. It not so efficient

So in theory we should be able to turn fat into other kind of energy, such as electricity or electromagnetic radiation

Can this be real?

Comment: Fat stored in the body isn't (all) useless. Your body evolved this capability as an energy store for hard times. You can (eventually) use fat to make electricity by turning a hand-cranked generator like those in numerous torches. Apart from surgery, "Working out mechanically" is probably an efficient way of depleting your stored energy reserves (fat).

Comment: @RedGrittyBrick I know fat is not useless, I mean there are more fat than we really need so much of them we stored is useless. I don't want surgery way because it like throw away fat we store as junk. I want to convert it to useful energy without feeling tire. for example we should able to use our fat to charge battery for smartphone while we standstill using it

Comment: yes it is possible and indeed it happens both inside the body (chemical energy transformations) and outside, using fat as a combustion material, however it shoud be noted that efficiency of the material/compound is also a major factor

Answer (score 3):

Fat can't just completely be changed to energy, there need to be chemical reactions in the body as the body metabolizes the fat.  Some energy in released by the metabolism.

By 1933, [Tainter and Cutting discovered](http://jama.jamanetwork.com/article.aspx?articleid=245872) that [dinitrophenol](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2,4-Dinitrophenol) causes cells in the body to waste energy.  So, yes, the energy of fat can be extracted without mechanical excercise.  However, PEOPLE HAVE DIED using this drug, so just do the mechanical excercise!

Also, being in a cold environment, especially in water would extract heat energy from your body and force the buring of fat without excercise.  In principle, the temperature difference between your body and cooler environment would cause heat flow that could do useful work, but the temperature difference is small so this isn't very practical. For example, a [body heat powered flashlight](http://www.smithsonianmag.com/innovation/this-flashlight-is-powered-by-the-touch-of-your-hand-180950226/?no-ist) has been made.

Comment: Ah yes, the results of looking for a get slim quick method always point back to the same conclusion. It's always generally a better idea to lose weight through healthy diet and exercising. Or to not put on that weight in the first place. People gain the weight through laziness in a lot of cases. Why would it make any sense whatsoever that laziness could also lose that weight?

Comment: @Jim I think that to make people life as lazy as possible to achieve goal is purpose of engineering

Comment: Your point about using temperature difference in cold place to force fat burning is so smart. Now I can picture some idea to achieve my goal, thanks

Comment: @Thaina No, the purpose of engineering is to apply science to solve problems. Not necessarily to make people's lives lazier. It's the people who give the engineers problems to solve that seem to only give problems whose solutions result in people's lives being lazier